# Use Regex to change values of a column conditionally in pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a very simple question: 
I've got a `DataFrame`, from which one of its columns is called Criterion. That column takes string values, which are:

```
df.Criterion.unique()

Nunca Fiscalizados Y Renuevan Convenio
Nunca Fiscalizados
Nunca Fiscalizado
Others
```

I want to merge `Nunca Fiscalizado` and `Nunca Fiscalizados` into just `Nunca Fiscalizados`.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
df['Criterion']=df['Criterion'].str.replace('Nunca Fiscalizad(o|os)$','Nunca Fiscalizados')
```

I thought that should do it, but that brings no change.
If I drop the `$`, I get:

```
df.Criterion.unique()

Nunca Fiscalizadoss Y Renuevan Convenio
Nunca Fiscalizadoss
Nunca Fiscalizado
Others
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably missing white space at the end of the actual data.

Comment: Now I feel dumb, it was actually that, sorry for not checking that first. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same condition by interchanging the position of 'o' and 'os'. Default the condition taking first possibility and replacing the string.

```
df.Criterion.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'Nunca Fiscalizad(o|os)','Nunca Fiscalizados',x))
```

output:

```
0    Nunca Fiscalizadoss Y Renuevan Convenio
1                        Nunca Fiscalizadoss
2                         Nunca Fiscalizados
3                                     Others
```

with regex

```
df.Criterion.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'Nunca Fiscalizad(os|o)','Nunca Fiscalizados',x))
```

output:

```
0    Nunca Fiscalizados Y Renuevan Convenio
1                        Nunca Fiscalizados
2                        Nunca Fiscalizados
3                                    Others
```